# Minimizing a function of a linear combination of data with Scipy

Tags: python, linux, optimization, scipy, linear-algebra

Suppose I have some matrix X where each row represents a time-series. For example, X could be a matrix of size 3 x 1000, which would mean that there are 3 time-series each consisting of 1000 time-points. In addition to X, I have one scalar for each time-series in X. I would like to find a linear combination

a[0] * X[0, :] + a[1] * X[1, :] + ... + a[n-1] * X[n-1, :]

that has the minimum value for some function F.

So, I attempted the following

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimization import minimize
def f(x):
    return 0 # for testing purposes
def obj(a,x):
    y = a*x
    return f(y)
minimize(obj, np.array([1,1]), args=np.array([[1,1],[2,2]]), method='nelder-mead')
```

So the second argument is the initial guess x0 (the coefficients a). The data given by args should get mapped to x (if I understand it correctly) and remains constant during the optimization.

However, I get the error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I guess my problem is pretty general one, so I hope someone would be able to help!

Comment: where do you define `f`?

Comment: I omitted it from here. It returns a scalar value. I believe the problem is somehow related to passing the arguments for minimize but I can't figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: That's not how a [mcve] works.

Comment: Well def f(x): return 0 for testing? Sorry, I was not aware of the requirements for posting

Comment: The point here is: It is extremely difficult for us to figure out what the problem is because we cannot see what code exactly produced the error. A good question tries to bring the error down to a minimal amount of code that reproduces the error and also can be run by others.

Comment: @cel Ok. I edited the question. The code should be now a minimal working example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90299/discussion-between-cel-and-mmh).

Comment: Could you give an example with a better f than a constant function, and also tell us what answer you expect?  In the example you've given, should f take a two-vector as parameter?

Comment: Code works for me using `from scipy.optimize import minimize`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

def f(val):
    return val**2

def obj(a, series):
    s = 0
    for row in series:
        for t in range(len(row)):
            s += f(a[t] * row[t])
    return s

ll_x = [[2, 3, 2, 6], [3, 5, 2, 7]]  # 2 series
l_a = [1 for _ in ll_x[0]]  # initial coeffs.

res = opt.minimize(obj, l_a, args=ll_x, method='nelder-mead')

for elem in sorted(res.items()):
    print(*elem)
```

(works for me with Python 3.4.3)